# Efficient upsert of pandas dataframe to MS SQL Server using pyodbc

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pandas, pyodbc

I'm trying to upsert a pandas dataframe to a MS SQL Server using pyodbc. I've used a similar approach before to do straight inserts, but the solution I've tried this time is incredibly slow. Is there a more streamlined way to accomplish an upsert than what I have?

```
sql_connect = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0}; Server=blank1; Database=blank2; UID=blank3; PWD=blank4')
cursor = sql_connect.cursor()

for index, row in bdf.iterrows():
    res = cursor.execute("UPDATE dbo.MPA_BOOK_RAW SET [SITE]=?, [SHIP_TO]=?, [PROD_LINE]=?, [GROUP_NUMBER]=?, [DESCRIPTION]=?, [ORDER_QTY]=?, [BPS_INCLUDE]=? WHERE [CUST]=? AND [ORDER_NUMBER]=? AND [ORDER_DATE]=? AND [PURCHASE_ORDER]=? AND [CHANNEL]=? AND [ITEM]=? AND [END_DT]=?", 
                    row['SITE'], 
                    row['SHIP_TO'],
                    row['PROD_LINE'],
                    row['GROUP_NUMBER'],
                    row['DESCRIPTION'],
                    row['ORDER_QTY'],
                    row['BPS_INCLUDE'],
                    row['CUST'],
                    row['ORDER_NUMBER'], 
                    row['ORDER_DATE'],
                    row['PURCHASE_ORDER'], 
                    row['CHANNEL'],
                    row['ITEM'],
                    row['END_DT'])

    if res.rowcount == 0:
            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO dbo.MPA_BOOK_RAW ([SITE], [CUST], [ORDER_NUMBER], [ORDER_DATE], [PURCHASE_ORDER], [CHANNEL], [SHIP_TO], [PROD_LINE], [GROUP_NUMBER], [DESCRIPTION], [ITEM], [ORDER_QTY], [END_DT], [BPS_INCLUDE]) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", 
                    row['SITE'], 
                    row['CUST'],
                    row['ORDER_NUMBER'], 
                    row['ORDER_DATE'],
                    row['PURCHASE_ORDER'], 
                    row['CHANNEL'],
                    row['SHIP_TO'],
                    row['PROD_LINE'],
                    row['GROUP_NUMBER'],
                    row['DESCRIPTION'],
                    row['ITEM'],
                    row['ORDER_QTY'],
                    row['END_DT'],
                    row['BPS_INCLUDE'])

    sql_connect.commit()

cursor.close()
sql_connect.close()
```

I tried the above with a five row sample of my original ~50k row dataframe and it worked fine. So the logic seems okay. It's just the speed that is an issue.

Comment: Maybe you should try Merge instead of Insert/Update: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Or maybe use pandas to_sql: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html to insert the whole dataframe into a temp table. Then merge from the temp table to MPA_BOOK_RAW.

Comment: As @vercelli mentions, avoid loop and dump data frame into a temp, staging table for final update/insert. Note: for `to_sql`, you need to use an [SQLAlchemy connection](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mssql.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.mssql.pyodbc) and not raw connection as you use here.

Answer (score 10):

Update, July 2022: You can save some typing by using [this function](https://gist.github.com/gordthompson/be1799bd68a12be58c880bb9c92158bc) to build the MERGE statement and perform the upsert for you.

---

Here is an example of an "upsert" using [MERGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```py
from pprint import pprint

import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy as sa

connection_string = (
    "Driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server;"
    "Server=192.168.0.199;"
    "UID=scott;PWD=tiger^5HHH;"
    "DATABASE=test;"
    "UseFMTONLY=Yes;"
)
sqlalchemy_url = sa.engine.URL.create(
    "mssql+pyodbc", query={"odbc_connect": connection_string}
)
engine = sa.create_engine(sqlalchemy_url, fast_executemany=True)

with engine.begin() as conn:
    # set up test environment
    conn.exec_driver_sql("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS actual_table;")
    conn.exec_driver_sql(
        """\
        CREATE TABLE actual_table (
            institution_no VARCHAR(3), 
            transit_no VARCHAR(5), 
            branch_name VARCHAR(50),
            CONSTRAINT PK_actual_table PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
                (institution_no, transit_no));
        """
    )
    # actual_table initial state
    conn.exec_driver_sql(
        """\
        INSERT INTO actual_table (institution_no, transit_no, branch_name) VALUES 
            ('002', '45678', 'Scotiabank branch #45678 - *** UPDATE NEEDED ***'),
            ('003', '67890', 'RBC branch #67890 - Sudbury, ON');
        """
    )
    # test data to be updated or inserted
    df_update = pd.DataFrame(
        [
            ("004", "12345", "TD branch #12345 - London, ON"),
            ("002", "45678", "Scotiabank branch #45678 - Timmins, ON"),
            ("004", "34567", "TD branch #34567 - Toronto, ON"),
        ],
        columns=["institution_no", "transit_no", "branch_name"],
    )

    # Here's where the real work begins ...
    #
    # Step 1: upload update data
    df_update.to_sql("#update_table", conn, index=False)
    #
    # Step 2: perform the "upsert"
    sql = """\
    MERGE actual_table WITH (HOLDLOCK) AS a
    USING (SELECT institution_no, transit_no, branch_name FROM #update_table) as u
    ON (a.institution_no = u.institution_no AND a.transit_no = u.transit_no)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE SET branch_name = u.branch_name
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (institution_no, transit_no, branch_name)
        VALUES (u.institution_no, u.transit_no, u.branch_name);
    """
    result = conn.exec_driver_sql(sql)

# verify results
with engine.begin() as conn:
    pprint(conn.exec_driver_sql("SELECT * FROM actual_table").fetchall())
    """console output:
    [('002', '45678', 'Scotiabank branch #45678 - Timmins, ON'),
     ('003', '67890', 'RBC branch #67890 - Sudbury, ON'),
     ('004', '12345', 'TD branch #12345 - London, ON'),
     ('004', '34567', 'TD branch #34567 - Toronto, ON')]
    """
```