# How to upsert pandas DataFrame to Microsoft SQL Server table?

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, sqlalchemy, upsert

I would like to upsert my pandas DataFrame into a SQL Server table. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61366664/2144390) has a workable solution for PostgreSQL, but T-SQL does not have an `ON CONFLICT` variant of `INSERT`. How can I accomplish the same thing for SQL Server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update, July 2022: You can save some typing by using [this function](https://gist.github.com/gordthompson/be1799bd68a12be58c880bb9c92158bc) to build the MERGE statement and perform the upsert for you.

---

SQL Server offers the [MERGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) statement:

```py
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy as sa

connection_string = (
    "Driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server;"
    "Server=192.168.0.199;"
    "UID=scott;PWD=tiger^5HHH;"
    "Database=test;"
    "UseFMTONLY=Yes;"
)
connection_url = sa.engine.URL.create(
    "mssql+pyodbc",
    query={"odbc_connect": connection_string}
)

engine = sa.create_engine(connection_url, fast_executemany=True)

with engine.begin() as conn:
    # step 0.0 - create test environment
    conn.exec_driver_sql("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS main_table")
    conn.exec_driver_sql(
        "CREATE TABLE main_table (id int primary key, txt varchar(50))"
    )
    conn.exec_driver_sql(
        "INSERT INTO main_table (id, txt) VALUES (1, 'row 1 old text')"
    )
    # step 0.1 - create DataFrame to UPSERT
    df = pd.DataFrame(
        [(2, "new row 2 text"), (1, "row 1 new text")], columns=["id", "txt"]
    )

    # step 1 - upload DataFrame to temporary table
    df.to_sql("#temp_table", conn, index=False, if_exists="replace")

    # step 2 - merge temp_table into main_table
    conn.exec_driver_sql(
        """\
        MERGE main_table WITH (HOLDLOCK) AS main
        USING (SELECT id, txt FROM #temp_table) AS temp
        ON (main.id = temp.id)
        WHEN MATCHED THEN
            UPDATE SET txt = temp.txt
        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
            INSERT (id, txt) VALUES (temp.id, temp.txt);
        """
    )

    # step 3 - confirm results
    result = conn.exec_driver_sql(
        "SELECT * FROM main_table ORDER BY id"
    ).fetchall()
    print(result)  
    # [(1, 'row 1 new text'), (2, 'new row 2 text')]
```

Comment: For an example that can be used with a compound (multi-column) primary key see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54612248/2144390).

Comment: I'm trying to replicate step 1 in my current use case:
I'm creating the sqlalchemy engine like so:  `sa.create_engine("ibm_db_sa+pyodbc://?driver=IBM i Access ODBC Driver&SYSTEM=XXX&;Port=21&UID=XXX&PWD=XXX&Database=")`

Then executing step 1:
`df1.to_sql("WWNEXPORT.TEMP", engine, index=False, if_exists="replace")`

But I receive the following error:

`sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42S02', '[42S02] [IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver][DB2 for i5/OS]SQL0204 - TABLES of type *FILE in SYSCAT not found. (-204) (SQLPrepare)')` 
Do you maybe know why?

Comment: @TheDude - Maybe try `df1.to_sql("TEMP", engine, schema="WWNEXPORT", index=False, if_exists="replace")`

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't the solution and I get the same error.
This is some additional information that comes with the error and that I couldn't post in the comment above due to the limitation of characters for comments:

`[SQL: SELECT "SYSCAT"."TABLES"."TABNAME"
FROM "SYSCAT"."TABLES"
WHERE "SYSCAT"."TABLES"."TABSCHEMA" = ? AND "SYSCAT"."TABLES"."TABNAME" = ?]
[parameters: ('WWNEXPORT', 'TEMP')]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/f405)`

I don't understand how and why this SQL statement is generated.

Comment: @TheDude - pandas `to_sql()` is calling SQLAlchemy `has_table()` to see if the table already exists, so SQLAlchemy is querying the SYSCAT (metadata) tables to see if your table shows up there. I have no experience with ibm_db_sa, unfortunately.

Comment: I checked the database for the SYSCAT table but didn't find anything. You don't have any experience working with DB2 as/400 database by any chance?